# Can I make this into a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#tab1").click(function(){
        loadTab(1);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

Would it be possible to make the code above into a function where I could just call it like

```
tab(TAB NUMBER HERE);
```

and have it add/remove the correct styles/divs?

The whole code for the script is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// array of pages to load
var pageUrl = new Array();          
pageUrl[1] = "page1.php";
pageUrl[2] = "somepage2.php";
pageUrl[3] = "lastpage3.php";

// function to load page into DIV
function loadTab(id) {
    if (pageUrl[id].length > 0) {
        $("#loading").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: pageUrl[id],
            cache: false,
            success: function (message) {
                $("#tabcontent").empty().append(message);
                $("#loading").hide();
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#tab1").click(function(){
        loadTab(1);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#tab2").click(function(){
        loadTab(2);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#tab3").click(function(){
        loadTab(3);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    });

    alert(window.location.hash);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a closure that will generate your "tab click function".  This way the `this` parameter when the event is called will still be the DOM object.

```
// this function creates an event function for a specified tab number.
function makeTabClick(tabNumber) {

  // this function is the actual event handler
  return function(e) {
    loadTab(tabNumber);
    $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  };
}

$('#tab1').click(makeTabClick(1));    
$('#tab2').click(makeTabClick(2));    
$('#tab3').click(makeTabClick(3));
```

Another alternative, a little more "jQuery" way - Create a plugin function that will generate the click handler you want.

```
$.fn.makeTab = function(tabNumber) {
  return this.click(function(e) {
    loadTab(tabNumber);
    $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
}

$('#tab1').makeTab(1);
$('#tab2').makeTab(2);
$('#tab3').makeTab(3);
```

Comment: +1 for a function that returns a function. Javascript was made for this kind of power.

Comment: great thanks, I took your function and combined the ajax part as well so it is all 1 smaller function now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function tab(num) {
    loadTab(num);
    $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

But if this is going to be a click handler of the anchor, then you can do this:

```
function tab(evt) {
    loadTab(num);
    $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').each(function(i) {
        if(evt.target != this)
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        else
            $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
}
```

If `#tab1` is a wrapper, then you can still get the wrapper (`#tab1`) using `this` (the anchor) in the `each`. All you have to do is make sure that the click event is placed on all appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs ?

Comment: Ok, I gotcha.  It's a great lib though! :)